# Embedding an SVG within another SVG as an Image is not appearing when referenced from HTML

Tags: html, svg

I wasn't sure how to word it correctly for the title, but here's what is happening.

I have two SVG files within the same folder, `shapes.svg` and `wrapper.svg`

`wrapper.svg` references shapes.svg with an image tag

```
<image x="-75" y="-100" width="150" height="150" xlink:href="shapes.svg" />
```

Now if I view `wrapper.svg` within a web browser directly, I can see it rendering `shapes.svg` perfectly. However, if I attempt to view `wrapper.svg` with a HTML file which is one directory above these two files, I can see all the markup of `wrapper.svg`, but it does not show `shapes.svg`.

Within the HTML file I am simple doing

```
<img src="svg/wrapper.svg" style="width:150px;height:150px;" />
```

The folder structure is as follows

- /index.html
- /svg/wrapper.svg
- /svg/shapes.svg

I found this a bit difficult to explain, and have attempted my best to relay the problem. If anybody needs me to further clarify anything at all, please do just ask me and I will reply promptly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For privacy reasons all images must be single files. You can have an image within your image but the inner image must be encoded as a data URI.

When thinking of an SVG as an image it helps to think... "If this was a raster image, could I do this".

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, thank you! I honestly did not expect somebody to understand my ramblings when trying to explain the problem at hand, but am glad you managed. :)